# Remove files (not directories) after GetFiles with WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, winscp, winscp-net

I'm trying to download files from a big tree of recursive directories, and I want the downloaded files to be removed after download. When I put `true` in `remove` parameter of `GetFiles`, it removes all the directories, but I want it to remove only the files and leave the directories empty. Is there any way to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the code of WinSCP extension [Recursively move files in directory tree to/from SFTP/FTP server while preserving source directory structure](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_moves_files_keeping_directory_structure).

---

Some alternatives:

- Do a regular download = do not set `remove` parameter of [`Session.GetFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles) to true.
- Iterate [`TransferOperationResult.Transfers`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoperationresult) returned by the `Session.GetFiles`.
- For each successful download of a file, call [`Session.RemoveFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_removefiles).

---

A more complicated, but more efficient (if you have a large amount of files) approach would be:

- Replicate the directory structure in a remote temporary folder.
- Move all the files there, directory by directory, using [`Session.MoveFile`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_movefile). Despite the name, the method accepts wildcards.
- Download and delete the temporary tree at once using `Session.GetFiles` with `remove` set to `true`.

Answer (score -2):

For anyone else looking this up, adding a `*` to the end of the path leaves the folder and just moves the files from the server.

`Path/*`